React native babelruntime Error Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault
I have been dealing with this error for a few days but I couldn't solve it. can you help please? I tried multiple times but it didn't work. He looked at many examples but it doesn't work.
Hello, I have been dealing with this error for a few days but I couldn't solve it. can you help please? I tried multiple times but it didn't work. He looked at many examples but it doesn't work.
react native version: 0.74.6
bable.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        alias: {
          '@env': './env.config.js',
          '@api': './src/api',
          '@assets': './src/assets',
          '@comp': './src/components',
          '@hooks': './src/hooks',
          '@providers': './src/providers',
          '@screens': './src/screens',
          '@search': './src/search',
          '@services': './src/services',
          '@stores': './src/stores',
          '@styles': './src/styles',
          '@utils': './src/utils',
          '@navigation': './src/navigation',
          '@constants': './src/constants',
        },
      },
    ],
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    // Eklememiz gereken babel runtime için plugin
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'
  ],
};

metro.config.js
const path = require('path');
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require('@react-native/metro-config');

console.log(__dirname,"__dirname");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
const {
  resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
} = defaultConfig;

const config = {
  transformer: {
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
    minifierPath: 'metro-minify-terser',
    minifierConfig: {
      compress: {
        drop_console: false,
        drop_debugger: false,
      },
    },
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: [
      ...assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
      'png',
      'jpg',
      'jpeg',
      'gif',
      'webp',
    ],
    sourceExts: [
      ...sourceExts,
      'svg',
      'js',
      'jsx',
      'json',
      'ts',
      'tsx',
      'cjs',
      'mjs',
    ],
    resolverMainFields: ['react-native', 'browser', 'main'],
    blockList: [
      /.*\/node_modules\/.*\/node_modules\/react-native\/.*/,
      /^\.(git|hg|svn)$/,
      /^\.git/,
      /^\.hg/,
      /\android\/.*/,
      /\ios\/.*/,
    ],
    platforms: ['ios', 'android', 'web'],
    disableHierarchicalLookup: true,
  },
  watchFolders: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'),
    path.resolve(__dirname),
  ],
  cacheStores: [
    new (require('metro-cache').FileStore)({
      root: path.join(__dirname, 'metro-cache'),
    }),
  ],
  maxWorkers: 4,
  resetCache: true,
  server: {
    port: 8081,
  },
};

module.exports = mergeConfig(defaultConfig, config);

emulator error screen

enter code here

